# Why is AWS asking for a Cognito Identity Pool when My schema is and based on API

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I don't understand AWS Authorization yet. I'm getting this error.

[GraphQLAPI - ensure credentials error No Cognito Identity pool provided for unauthenticated access](https://stackoverflow.com)

I thought by providing an API key this would just work like when you request from any other API.

This is my schema:

```
type art
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: public, operations: [read], provider: iam }
      { allow: public, provider: apiKey }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  title: String! @index(name: "artByTitle", queryField: "artByTitle")
  artist: String
  medium: String!
  height: Int!
  width: Int!
  depth: Int!
  framed: Boolean!
  priceInCents: Int!
  red: Int!
  green: Int!
  blue: Int!
  filename: String!
  quantity: Int!
  category: artCategory @hasOne
}

type artCategory
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: public, operations: [read], provider: iam }
      { allow: public, provider: apiKey }
    ]
  ) {
  name: String!
    @index(name: "artCategoryByName", queryField: "artCategoryByName")
}
```

This is my request:

Note that this is done with an .mjs file so the imports are a little weird.

```
import * as path from "path";
import { createRequire } from 'module';
import { Amplify, API, graphqlOperation, Logger } from 'aws-amplify';
import { GRAPHQL_AUTH_MODE } from '@aws-amplify/api';
const awsPath = path.resolve('../../src/aws-exports.js');
const awsconfig = createRequire(awsPath);
//import { createArt } from "../../src/graphql/mutations.ts";
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

const createArt = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation CreateArt(
    $input: CreateArtInput!
    $condition: ModelArtConditionInput
  ) {
    createArt(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
      id
      title
      artist
      medium
      height
      width
      depth
      framed
      priceInCents
      red
      green
      blue
      filename
      quantity
      category {
        name
        id
        createdAt
        updatedAt
        __typename
      }
      createdAt
      updatedAt
      artCategoryId
      __typename
    }
  }
`;

export async function addArtToAPI(art) {
  // art = JSON.stringify(art);
  console.log("art: ", art);
  console.log("Sending to API");
  try {
    await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createArt, {
      variables:
      {
        input:
        {
          title: art.title,
          artist: art.artist,
          medium: art.medium,
          height: art.height,
          width: art.width,
          depth: art.depth,
          framed: art.framed,// Convert string to boolean
          priceInCents: art.price, // Convert price to cents
          red: art.red,
          green: art.green,
          blue: art.blue,
          filename: art.filename,
          quantity: art.quantity,
          category: art.category,
        }
      }
    }),
       {
         headers: {
           'x-api-key': MY.API.KEY
         }
       }
    );

    const createdArt = response.data.createArt;
    console.log('Created Art:', createdArt);

  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Unable to Create Art: ", error);
  }
};
```

Is my schema wrong? Or am I supposed to include more info in the headers?

Please use examples if you understand the problem because I'm finding AWS so confusing.

I worked with ChatGPT to get this far but now I'm stuck because it's giving me standard answers without any examples.

Comment: What authorization mode do you want to provide to the application?